# Mac option+number keyboard characters no longer working

Tags: mac, keyboard, special-characters

Normally, <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd> creates a bullet point; <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> creates a TM; etc.

However, on my Mac, <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>…<kbd>9</kbd> does nothing. Other diacritics & chars using the option key work fine.

It doesn't matter what application I'm in; this is a system-wide issue.

How did I get myself in this messed-up setting?

Answer (score 1):

You may have accidentally switched keyboard layouts.

Check the “Input Sources” tab of the “Language & Text” preference pane of *System Preferences* (or try searching for “keyboard layout” in *System Preferences*). You can disable the layouts you do not need.

If you enable the menu extra (mark the “Show Input menu in menu bar” checkbox), you can use it to see which keyboard layout is active and activate any of the enabled layouts.